# Not able to generate key in IBM Bluemix key Protect

Tags: ibm-cloud, key-protect

I am playing around with IBM Bluemix Key Protect, Created the service but I am not able to generate the key.

Comment: Are you using the UI? What did you try?

Comment: Did you encounter any error messages? More information is needed to help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes I tried with UI as well as API. I am getting "Failedd: Add Key Failed" error.

Comment: Do you already have keys, how many? What algorithm did you select? Have you tried manually entering a key and did that work?

Comment: No I don't have any key, I selected the default algorithm. Yes I trying manually entering a key and that did not work.